# Resized Page - Button submitting and not using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatables

Update, seems it is also happening when i go onto the next page (fullscreen this time).

---

I'm hoping someone could possible help me as this has been driving me crazy. I have a `table` full off orders which each `row` has a `button`. This `button` when `submitted` will show an `alert`.

I am using data-tables (Responsive), and when the `table` is all on the screen, the `button` works as intended. However, when the screen is resized and the `button` goes within the + icon to expand the `row`. The `button` is not running the `jquery` and is submitting the `page`.

I have no idea how to fix this and was wondering if there is a workaround. Here is a sample of the code if it helps.

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Order Number</th>
      <th>Button</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          <?php echo $order['OrderNumber']; ?>
        </th>
        <td>
          <form id="<?php echo $order['OrderNumber']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At the bottom of the page:

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
  <script>
    $('#<?php echo $order['OrderNumber']; ?>').on('submit', function () {
      alert('Form submitted!');
      return false;
    });
  </script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I have no idea why it isn't working when the `table` is resized.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**delegated event handler**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead :

```
$('#datatable-buttons').on('submit', '#<?php echo $order['OrderNumber'];?>', function() {
  alert('Form submitted!');
  return false;
});
```

Your event handler does not work because the form not exists in dom at the time of declaration.

---

But all those dedicated `#id` based event handlers is completely unnecessary. A single (delegated) handler is sufficient :

```
$('#datatable-buttons').on('submit', 'form', function () {
  alert('Form ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' submitted!');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate you could try something like this for the alert

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-       bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Order Number</th>
  <th>Button</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">
      <?php echo $order['OrderNumber']; ?>
    </th>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btnPress" id="<?php echo $order['OrderNumber']; ?>">Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Bottom

```
 <script>
$('.btnPress').on('click', function () {
  alert('Form submitted!');
  alert(this.id);
});
</script>
```